# Stacked Area Chart, fixed y axis label width

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I am creating a JFreeChart stacked area chart.

I want my *y* axis label's width to be fixed, and I don't want to shift the chart as the width increases. See the image explaining the problem.

[image: error]

I am facing similar problem as posted on the [JFreeChart forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20150608232351/http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=16218). As per the forum it is fixed, but it is not yet released. Does any body knows its fix. We can't wait for next release, does any body knows a hack which we can apply?

Hoping for some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to override the findMaximumTickLabelWidth() for rangeaxis of the chart. The maximum width can be hardcoded to a specific value or can be taken as max value of maximum width and calculated maximum width.

Comment: woooohoooooo ...wow that's awsome vegeta ... it worked like charm ... you saved me ...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider a `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389045/230513). A `CombinedDomainXYPlot` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513).

Answer (score 1):

There is another method to get the plots aligned. You can reserve some space on the left, right top or bottom of your plot to display the Range axes.

```
      AxisSpace space = new AxisSpace();
      space.setRight(50); //reserved space on the left side of the plot
      space.setLeft(50);
      plot.setFixedRangeAxisSpace(space);
      plot2.setFixedRangeAxisSpace(space);
```

I know, this is not the best solution for multiple plots. But you can solve the problem in a quick way.