# How to Change the JFree Chart without overlapping?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Hi I have attached the screen shot for your consideration. I'm using the Jfree chart for the bar diagram and using the percentage also. In some scenario the PERCENTAGE and the COUNT would be overlapped. So please give me the suggestion from overlapping in the JFree chart.

[image]

### My sample code Is:

```
public void writeOccurrenceBasedParetoChart(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "writeOccurrenceBasedParetoChart";
        log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

         CategoryDataset dataset1 = createDataSetForPercentBasedChart1();
         CategoryDataset dataset2 = createDataSetForPercentBasedChart2();
         String rangeAxisLabel = "";
         String numOfSupplrs = "";
         //Behind Schedule "4"
         if(searchRatingElement.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
         {           
             System.out.println("*******************searchRatingElement"+searchRatingElement);
             rangeAxisLabel = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.ovrshptpcs");
         }
         else 
         {
             rangeAxisLabel = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.ovrshptpcs");
         }

         JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "",       // chart title
                "",               // domain axis label
                rangeAxisLabel,                  // range axis label
                dataset1,                  // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                true,                     // include legend
                true,                     // tooltips?
                false                     // URLs?
            );

            // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...

            // set the background color for the chart...
            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
            CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);


            plot.setDataset(1, dataset2);
            plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

            CategoryItemRenderer renderer1 = plot.getRenderer();
            renderer1.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0,new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

                public String generateRowLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                public String generateLabel(final CategoryDataset dataset1,final int series,final int category) {
                    String result = null;
                    //CHAPTER 12. ITEM LABELS 91
                    final Number value = dataset1.getValue(series, category);
                    if (value != null) {
                    final double v = value.doubleValue();
                    if (v > 0) {
                    result = value.toString(); // could apply formatting here
                    }
                    }
                    return result;
                    }


                public String generateColumnLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            });
            renderer1.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0,true);

            BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
            renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
            renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0,Color.BLACK);
            renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
            renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.02);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0,new Color(170, 0, 85));          

            CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
            domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(.6));  
            domainAxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
            domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));

             //Behind Schedule "4"
             if(searchRatingElement.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
             {           
                 System.out.println("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||searchRatingElement"+searchRatingElement);
                 numOfSupplrs = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.bhndschpctforchart");
             }
             else 
             {
                 numOfSupplrs = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.ovrshptpctforchart");
             }

            ValueAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis(numOfSupplrs);
            axis2.setLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));    
            axis2.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            //if(!this.isValueDataZeros)
                //axis2.setRange(0,13);
            plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);

            NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
           // if(!this.isNumberDataZeros)
                //rangeAxis.setRange(0,90);
           //rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1)); 
           rangeAxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14));
           rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 14));

            LineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
            renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
            /*Start */
            renderer2.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0,new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

                public String generateRowLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                public String generateLabel(final CategoryDataset dataset1,final int series,final int category) {
                    String result = null;
                    //CHAPTER 12. ITEM LABELS 91
                    final Number value = dataset1.getValue(series, category);
                    if (value != null) {
                    final double v = value.doubleValue();
                    if (v > 0) {
                    result = value.toString(); // could apply formatting here
                    }
                    }
                    return result;
                    }


                public String generateColumnLabel(final CategoryDataset arg0, final int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            });
            renderer2.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0,true);
            /* End */
            plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
            plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);

            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart,
                    1150, 450);
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    public DefaultCategoryDataset createDataSetForPercentBasedChart1()
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "createDataSetForPercentBasedChart1";
        log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSetForOccurrenceBasedChart = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        boolean flagForPercentPareto = false;
        String occurrenceCountLabelName = null;
        try
        {
            if(paretoReportBasedDataQO != null && paretoReportBasedDataQO.size()>0)
            {
                //Behind Schedule "4"
                if(searchRatingElement.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
                {            
                    occurrenceCountLabelName = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.bhndschpctforchart");
                }
                else 
                {
                    occurrenceCountLabelName = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.ovrshptpcs");
                }
                if(!flagForPercentPareto)
                {
                    for(int i =0;i<paretoReportBasedDataQO.size();i++)
                    {
                        dataSetForOccurrenceBasedChart.addValue(paretoReportBasedDataQO.get(i).getOverShipmentPiecesCount(), occurrenceCountLabelName, paretoReportBasedDataQO.get(i).getSupplierName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exceptionOccurrenceBasedChart)
        {
            flagForPercentPareto = true;
            System.out.println("Exception In createDataSetForPercentBasedChart1 : "+exceptionOccurrenceBasedChart.getMessage());
        }

        log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
        return dataSetForOccurrenceBasedChart;
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    public DefaultCategoryDataset createDataSetForPercentBasedChart2()
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "createDataSetForPercentBasedChart2";
        log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSetForOccurrenceBasedChart = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        boolean flagForPercentPareto = false;
        String occurrenceCountLabelName = null;
        try
        {
            if(paretoReportBasedDataQO != null && paretoReportBasedDataQO.size()>0)
            {
                if(searchRatingElement.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
                {            
                    occurrenceCountLabelName = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.bhndschpctforchart");
                }
                else 
                {
                    occurrenceCountLabelName = I18nMessageUtil.getMessage(CommonUtil.getLocale(), "label.reports.wdid.ovrshptpctforchart");
                }
                if(!flagForPercentPareto)
                {
                    for(int i =0;i<paretoReportBasedDataQO.size();i++)
                    {
                        dataSetForOccurrenceBasedChart.addValue(paretoReportBasedDataQO.get(i).getOverShipmentPercentageCount(), occurrenceCountLabelName, paretoReportBasedDataQO.get(i).getSupplierName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exceptionOccurrenceBasedChart)
        {
            flagForPercentPareto = true;
            System.out.println("Exception In createDataSetForPercentBasedChart2 : "+exceptionOccurrenceBasedChart.getMessage());
        }

        log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
        return dataSetForOccurrenceBasedChart;
    }
```

But the image and code is different. I posted the image is sample...

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389045/230513) and [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513) illustrates `CombinedDomainXYPlot`.

Comment: You do not  appear to be using `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot`. Do you _want_ overlap or _not want_ overlap?

Comment: This it sounds like `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot` is your best bet.

Comment: how can i use the CombinedDomainCategoryPlot in the above code..do you havea any idea about that...please give me the suggestion. I saw the code where u pasted the link but still i don't understand about that.

Comment: If it helps, there are more examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/Combined-Chart.htm). For more specific help, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you encounter.